# Ansible lineinfile module to replace

Tags: replace, ansible, line, special-characters

I have been trying to replace a option  #$ActionFileEnableSync on
for /etc/rsyslog.conf file with $ActionFileEnableSync on. I have used replace module

```
- replace:
      path: /etc/rsyslog.conf
      regexp: '^#\s*^$\s*ActionFileEnableSync on.*$'
      line: '$ActionFileEnableSync on'
```

And also I have tried to use lineinfile module

```
 - lineinfile:
        dest: /etc/rsyslog.conf
        regexp: (^#\\$ActionFileEnableSync on)
        line: "$ActionFileEnableSync on"
```

But none seems to work,either it doesn't replace or keeps on adding a new line

Comment: Replace the entire file as a template. It's absurd that you wouldn't have administrative control oven the whole file.

Comment: So what was the result of running your `replace` task?

Comment: It is not getting replaced at all

Comment: Oh! So you have discovered a hidden argument `line` in the `regexp` module! Congratulations! It’s not doing much (or you have not yet discovered it’s secret functionality), but at least it doesn’t throw a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Use lineinfile to set a specific line in a file.

Your regexp looks wrong. Why is 'on' in the regexp? Isn't it supposed to set the value to 'on' when the existing line says 'off'?

Also, the regexp should match the line when it's already 'on', commented out or not. Otherwise, Ansible will append a line at every run.

Try something like:

```
regexp: ^[#\s]*\$ActionFileEnableSync
```

This should replace $ActionFileEnableSync following any combination of comment marks and whitespace.